# $validator->safe()->except('field') returning all data in request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

In my laravel 10.x project,

```php
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'displayed_total_rate' => 'required|numeric',
      // and many more fields validations...
    ]);
```

I want to get all validated fields except `displayed_total_rate`

```
$booking_data = $validator->safe()->except(['displayed_total_rate']);
```

but the `$booking_data` contain all fields including `displayed_total_rate`

I don't want to use `$request->except('displayed_total_rate');` because it may contain all fields that are not in validator and `$request->only(['field_1',])` and it's not not suitable because there are many more fields inside validator.

Comment: How about just `unset` after getting the value of `$validator->safe()` ?

Comment: btw, would there be a difference if you used FormRequest instead of calling the validator inside the controller ? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: So `$booking_data['displayed_total_rate']` contains value?  
If yes why don't you just use `unset($booking_data['displayed_total_rate']);`  after getting validated data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use forget() for this, it removes a given key / value pair from a array. For example

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'displayed_total_rate' => 'required|numeric',
  // and many more fields validations...
]);
$booking_data = $validator->safe();
$booking_data = $booking_data->forget('displayed_total_rate');
```

i assume that this key will always be present becouse if request dont have that key validation will fail, so you don't need to check if it is even there. Also i sugest you to put this validation to seperate file.